# Looking for a book on Probability and Statistics.

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request

I am looking for a book or website on mathematical theory of probability and statistics for preparation of an examination. The syllabus written in the unit 4 of this [document](http://csirhrdg.res.in/mcs_ma_sylbs.pdf). Only multiple choice questions are given to see if the candidate know the subject matter and eligibility of applying the knowledge. The matter is known to me. I want to revise the subject and want to increase my skills but do not want to read a long book.

Thank you for suggestion. If you have a soft copy please share a link.

Answer (score 1):

Grimmett and Stirzaker, *Probability and Random Processes* is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

You could also check these online resources, whose level of detail and difficulty are intermediate:

1. E-handbook of  statistical methods (http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/index.htm)
2. Virtual Laboratories in Probability and Statistics (http://www.randomservices.org/random/index.html)
3. Lectures on probability and statistics (http://www.statlect.com/)

At a much more basic level, you can have a look at:

1. Stattrek (http://www.stattrek.com/)