# Statistic Textbooks

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request

What is a good textbook for introductions to continuous and discrete distributions? The one that my university offers is a thin scrap put together by the department. Could I get some recommendations on what the standard introduction textbook to probabilities and statistics.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532305/looking-for-a-book-on-probability-and-statistics

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend *"A first course in probability"* by Sheldon Ross. *"Schaum's Outline of Theory and Problems of Probability"* is a good place to get lots of practice problems. In case you want an advanced treatment of the subject, you can refer to *"Probability and Random Processes for Electrical and Computer Engineers"* by John A. Gubner and *"Probability and Random Processes"* by Grimmett and Stirzaker.

Comment: How in depth does Sheldon Ross's book go into? It seems to me that the topics covered in an undergraduate statistic course are less defined than a calculus one. Will the topics covered in the first textbook you recommend carry over into an intermediate level Probability and Statistic course? Thanks for your input!

Comment: Yes, they will certainly carry over to an intermediate probability or random processes class. However, for a proper statistics class, I would recommend *Probability and Statistical Inference* by Hogg, Tanis, and Rao. This book includes material from statistics as well (hypothesis testing, confidence intervals, estimation theory etc.) in addition to probability fundamentals. Needless to say, you cannot proceed with statistics without having a decent background in probability.